# How do I access grpc client ssl certificate information from server side?

Tags: authentication, ssl, grpc

I am testing out a client/server grpc app, since this is a test, both client and server have self-signed certificates. I used SslCredentials and SslServerCredentials (on the server side, I pass in the certificate and the key, on the client side, I pass in server certificate and client certificate and client key), and the handshake works fine. However, when I try to access client certificate information from the server side, I found that there is no relevant information at all in the AuthContext object (I printed out all the properties and do not see anything related to the client certificate). What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: I realized that I was not setting correct client authentication options at the server side, when that is properly set, I do see the relevant information in the AuthContext object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `AuthContext` works. Also, you may access the credential information programmatically via gRPC's channel tracing library -- Channelz.

Here is an example of how to set it up: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/debug

The info you are looking for is located at the socket level: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/channelz/channelz.proto#L240

Alternatively, you can try to use a command line tool (https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpcdebug) to visualize the tracing data you collected from the app.